# Remove/dissolve parts in ESRI line feature class

Tags: arcgis-10.1, line

I am using ESRI ArcGIS 10.1.

I have a line which has been dissolved, having initially been composed of 4 features. I want to remove these parts, properly dissolving it into one continuous feature. I tried using the Unsplit Lines tool but no luck.

[image: line parts]

Additionally, once dissolved it places the final vertex at a mid point, not the end of the line:

[image: end point]

This proves very difficult to manually correct. Curiously, the position of the end point is the end point of the right most line from the four that this was initially dissolved from.

If anyone knows how to get ridd of these parts, I'd appreciate it.

I am wondering if it is because there is an infinitessimally small distance between parts, but it seems they're snapped together.

Comment: It seems to say here

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Unsplitting_connected_polylines/010300000172000000/

that I can do this with the production editing extension, but I don’t have this.

Any other solutions?

Wil

Comment: Use Dissolve with Unsplit Line option. Not Unsplit Line tool.

Comment: Have you tried the Repair geometry tool? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003v000000

Comment: Dissolve with unsplit does not work, at least not in all cases. I still have an end vertex in the middle of a line feature after trying that approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ArcInfo 10.1 [split lines at vertices](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000003z000000) tool creates a new line feature class containing a new line feature for each set of 2 vertices from the original feature class.

Run this tool and then

- Start an edit session and edit your new line.shp.
- Next select all the lines.
- Select `Merge` from the Editor drop down menu
- Select one of the lines in the dialogue window
- Click OK merging all the lines into the selected feature.

This should give you one continuous line feature

Comment: Note: This required ArcInfo/Advanced.

Comment: I was told to do this by ESRI support as well.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a multi-part line now. The 4 lines are a single multipart record. Run "Multipart to SinglePart" to explode the lines into individual features. Then run Dissolve with Unsplit_lines or run Unsplit lines.

Answer (score -1):

Quick and dirty, create a new feature and trace the existing feature. Delete the old one.

The problem is that you have 4 separate features that are not connected. Part 2 and 4 are essentially points. For the line to dissolve you would need Part 2 Vertex 0 to equal Part 1 Vertex 2 and Part 2 Vertex 1 to equal Part 3 Vertex 0. This would dissolve Parts 1-3 into a single feature.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. yes i had thought of doing this but i have a number of lines, some of which are complex. Yes, looking at the coordinate listing the end point's not coincident with the starting point of the next line. This dataset is at fault. Oh and Part 3 I truncated the listing, there are more vertices.